# Expression: Il nous fait la morale

Tags: expressions, homonymes

Je sais que la morale c'est le fait d'être optimiste, portant une énergie positive et être satisfait de l'avenir en quelque sorte, par contre je ne comprends pas qu'est-ce que ça veut dire lorsque quelqu’un dit dans un groupe de potes à l'un de ses potes :

> **Mais c'est inévitable, il nous fait déjà la morale**

Quelle est la différence entre moral et morale ?

Comment: Je pense que tu confonds "le moral" et "la morale" tel qu'employée ici dans l'expression "faire la morale"

Comment: ca devrait etre le moral dans ce contexte ?

Comment: Non. Mais le fait d'être optimiste, c'est avoir le moral, pas la morale. Ce sont 2 mots différents avec leur propre définition...

Comment: *Faire la morale à quelqu'un, c'est lui faire des reproches sur sa conduite, lui donner des conseils sur sa conduite future.* Source [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/morale)

Answer (score 1):

Il y a une différence entre **LE moral** qui concerne l'ensemble des facultés mentales de quelqu'un ou bien son état psychologique, ce qui lui permet de surmonter un situation comme *le moral d'un malade, d'une personne qui cherche un travail...* et **LA morale** qui peut signifier entre autres *l'ensemble de règles de conduite* auxquelles on doit adhérer dans une situation particulière.

Comment: Moralité: un dictionnaire peut répondre à beaucoup de questions.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci !